# Check which id is visible on scroll regex

Tags: javascript

I have a list of div which is visible to users on scroll.

```
<div class="fdsfad" id="idd0">
--------
<div>

<div class="fdsfad" id="idd1">
--------
<div>

<div class="fdsfad" id="idd2">
--------
<div>

<div class="fdsfad" id="idd3">
--------
<div>

<div class="fdsfad" id="idd4">
--------
<div>

<div class="fdsfad" id="idd5">
--------
<div>

<div class="fdsfad" id="idd6">
--------
<div>
```

On scroll, I want to check which `idd` is in viewport. I am thinking something like:

```
window.addEventListener("scroll", function (e) {
            console.log(e);
            // console.log(document.querySelectorAll('[id^="idd"]'));
            // if ( document.getElementById("idd"+cur_id).length !== 0)
            // {
            //  // console.log("the element is visible.");
            // }
         });
```

I want to know exact id of the element which is visible with regex `idd*`.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: try `elementFromPoint()` instead of looping.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Can you please elaborate a little bit?

Comment: There are many plugins available on net to check the existence of the element in viewport, one of them widely used is jquery-waypoints

Comment: I am coding with Reactjs. So, stuck with Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

It's been 9 hours, and no answer. So, I am posting the hack I used.

Firstly, I put all my div inside another div:

```
<div id="mainContent">
// mydiv

</div>
```

Now, I calculated the hight after scrolling:

```
 window.addEventListener("scroll", function (e) {
        let div_height = document.getElementsByClassName("tupleOuterDiv")[1].clientHeight;
        let curr_scroll_position = Math.abs(document.getElementById("mainContent").getBoundingClientRect().top);
         // console.log("div_height",div_height);
         // console.log("curr_scroll_position",curr_scroll_position);
            let last_index = (Math.floor((curr_scroll_position/div_height)))


         });
```

I calculated individual div height:

```
let div_height = document.getElementsByClassName("tupleOuterDiv")[1].clientHeight;
```

then I calculated total scrolled height:

```
let curr_scroll_position = Math.abs(document.getElementById("mainContent").getBoundingClientRect().top);
```

And then, `curr_scroll_position/div_height` gives the index of the div.